# Why doesn't setting a nvarchar variable to null return nothing in this stored proc?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When @RadioServiceGroup is set to NULL, I want to return all the records from the sbi_l_radioservicecodes table which has about 120 records.  However, when I execute the following procedure and set the @RadioServiceGroup to NULL, it returns no records.  Here is the stored proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRadioServiceCodes] 
@RadioServiceGroup nvarchar(1000) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
IF(@RadioServiceGroup = NULL)
    BEGIN
        SELECT rsc.RadioService
        FROM sbi_l_radioservicecodes rsc    
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN       
        SELECT rsc.RadioService
        FROM sbi_l_radioservicecodes rsc
        WHERE rsc.RadioServiceGroup = @RadioServiceGroup    
    END
END
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try "IS NULL" instead of "= NULL"

Comment: Wow. Thanks, I feel like a certified idiot.  Curious, is it just a syntax thing on why = does not work on nvarchar for NULL

Comment: By definition, NULL does not "equal" anything, so "NULL = NULL" is false.

Comment: Ok. That makes much more sense. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't know the why of it.  I just know it because I already have my idiot certification.

Comment: As James alluded to, NULL means "unknown". You can't say that an unknown value is equal to a different unknown value, so it evaluates as false to ask if NULL = NULL

Comment: And to check if the column is not null it's "@column is not null"

Answer (score 3):

> Curious, is it just a syntax thing on why = does not work on nvarchar for NULL

Some people are saying that NULL = NULL evaluates to false.  This is wrong.  NULL = NULL evaluates to NULL.

The result (NULL) is not true, so the ELSE condition is run.

See also : [ThreeValuedLogic on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_null#Three-valued_logic_.283VL.29)

Another affect you should be aware of - Concatenation:  NULL + @SomeVar evaluates to NULL.  This can wipe out a computed string unexpectedly.

Comment: @Martin Smith, Your comment evaluates to null.

Answer (score 1):

You can cut out the `If` completely.  Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRadioServiceCodes] 
@RadioServiceGroup nvarchar(1000) = NULL
AS
BEGIN              
    SELECT rsc.RadioService
    FROM sbi_l_radioservicecodes rsc
    WHERE 
        rsc.RadioServiceGroup = @RadioServiceGroup    
        OR @RadioServiceGroup IS NULL
END
```

Make sure you add any necessary parentheses to group these if the where clause gets more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Use "IS NULL" instead of "= NULL"

Alternatively, to make "= NULL" work you can write "SET ANSI_NULLS OFF" before "CREATE PROCEDURE".